# How to identify the class of a Modal View controller?

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, cocoa-touch

In my application, I have to present two modal view controllers one above the other.

Lets say Modal View Controller B is placed over Modal View Controller A. Sometimes, there will be only A and no B.

I want to check from A that whether the top Modal View Controller is B. I know there is a method NSStringFromClass() but I can apply that only if I get the top Modal View Controller.

Answer (score 3):

use `(BOOL)[[youObjectInstance isKindOfClass:[ControllerClassYouWantToCheckAgainst class]]`

Documentation here:
https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Protocols/NSObject_Protocol/Reference/NSObject.html#//apple_ref/occ/intfm/NSObject/isKindOfClass:

Comment: well actually the problem is, i am not able to get that "youObjectInstance" directly. Is there a way I can access the Modal View Controllers currently being displayed?